# how to save pin onto phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms to build this app

**What I am trying to do:** I am not sure what it calls but I am creating login but rather than username/password, I am doing a 'Enter Pin to Unclock' App. Pin will be 4 digits that user can set up on start of App.

To do this I only have 2 options:

1. Use Xamarin "System Preference" to save pin bc its easy to set up just as cookie. but I dont know how long this last. 1 year? 10 years?
2. I could set up local database onto phone, but is that ready a good idea just to save 4 digits into full database?

**My Question:** I am leaning toward System Preference. Which option will work best for what I am trying to do? and how long xamarin system preference lasts?

Comment: for a PIN you should use Secure Storage.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios

Comment: Preferences is just store in a file, so it will last until the app is uninstalled

Comment: thanks, SecureStorage is helpful i am def going to use that. Question, do you know if SecureStorage also last until app is uninstalled like preferences? I am assuming it should

Comment: Yes, it does. It may also save to iCloud or Android backup, which can cause it to persist between installs. Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("Name", Value);
```